# Integral of $e^\left(1/z^2\right)$ around $|z|=1$ in the complex plane

Tags: residue-calculus, complex-integration, laurent-series

$e^\left(1/z^2\right)$ has an essential singularity at $0.$ Don't know how to do this integral.

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the coefficient $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of $e^{1/z^2}$ around $0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You have to surround your MathJax expressions with `$` signs to get them to formatted correctly.  Please look at how I've edited your question.  As to the question itself, have you tried making a change of variables in the integral?

Comment: In particular, do not try to do this by finding an antiderivative of $e^{1/z^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the circle $z=\exp{i\theta}$.  For any given value of $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi$ compare $\exp(1/z^2) \Delta z$ between $\theta$ and $\theta+\Delta \theta$ with $\exp(1/z^2) \Delta z$ between $\theta+\pi$ and $\theta+\pi+\Delta \theta$.  You should see they are negatives of each other, since the integrand is an even function, forcing a zero Riemann sum.  Thus, the contour integral must be zero.

We can adapt this symmetry based argument to prove that  when you integrate a Laurent series around an isolated singularity at $z=z_0$ all terms will give zero, except for the term with $(z-z_0)^{-1}$.  That's how contour integrals get reduced to residue values based on the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$.  In this problem that coefficient is zero so the contour integral is zero, too.